# Docker Couchbase in docker-compose : Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8091: Connection refused wh

Tags: curl, docker, docker-compose, couchbase

I have created docker image for couchbase. i am able to run standalone couchbase image it is working fine but while using it with docker-compose (Storm) it is giving me following error :

```
couchbase_1   | Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
couchbase_1   | *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
couchbase_1   |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
couchbase_1   |                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8091 failed: Connection refused
couchbase_1   | * Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8091: Connection refused
couchbase_1   | * Closing connection 0
couchbase_1   | curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8091: Connection refused
stormcluster_couchbase_1 exited with code 7
```

I am calling configure.sh file from docker file , curl commands from that file are as follows :

```
curl --fail -v -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default -d memoryQuota=300 -d indexMemoryQuota=300
curl --fail -v http://127.0.0.1:8091/node/controller/setupServices -d services=kv%2Cn1ql%2Cindex
curl --fail -v http://127.0.0.1:8091/settings/web -d port=8091 -d username=XXX-d password=XXX
```

---

This is my yaml file :

```
couchbase:
  image: xyz/test
  ports:
    - "8091:8091"
    - "22"
zookeeper:
  image: xyz/storm-zookeeper 
  ports: 
    - "49181:2181"
    - "22"
nimbus:
  image: xyz/storm-nimbus
  ports:
    - "49773:3773"
    - "49772:3772"
    - "49627:6627"
    - "22"
  links: 
    - zookeeper:zk
    - couchbase:cb
supervisor:
  image: xyz/storm-supervisor
  ports:
    - "8000"
    - "22"
  links: 
    - nimbus:nimbus
    - zookeeper:zk
    - couchbase:cb
    - couchbase:couchbase.docker
ui:
  image: xyz/storm-ui
  ports:
    - "49080:8080"
    - "22"
  links: 
    - nimbus:nimbus
    - zookeeper:zk
    - couchbase:cb
    - couchbase:couchbase.docker
```

Comment: can you post docker-compose.yml pls!? thnx

Comment: Please, add your compose file.

Answer (score 0):

This is my yaml file :

couchbase:
  image: xyz/test
  ports:
    - "8091:8091"
    - "22"
zookeeper:
  image: xyz/storm-zookeeper 
  ports: 
    - "49181:2181"
    - "22"
nimbus:
  image: xyz/storm-nimbus
  ports:
    - "49773:3773"
    - "49772:3772"
    - "49627:6627"
    - "22"
  links: 
    - zookeeper:zk
    - couchbase:cb
supervisor:
  image: xyz/storm-supervisor
  ports:
    - "8000"
    - "22"
  links: 
    - nimbus:nimbus
    - zookeeper:zk
    - couchbase:cb
    - couchbase:couchbase.docker
ui:
  image: xyz/storm-ui
  ports:
    - "49080:8080"
    - "22"
  links: 
    - nimbus:nimbus
    - zookeeper:zk
    - couchbase:cb
    - couchbase:couchbase.docker

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are trying to access one container from another container using `localhost`. This will not work.

You are using container links, which will allow containers to communictae with one another. 
The script that is running is trying to reach caouchbase db. You need to replace `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` with `cb` as the hostname alias you specified in the composefile.

Thus replace `http://127.0.0.1:8091` with `http://cb:8091` and the connection should work.

Comment: after the replacement getting an error like :couchbase_1   | Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
couchbase_1   | * getaddrinfo(3) failed for cb:8091
couchbase_1   | * Couldn't resolve host 'cb'
couchbase_1   | * Closing connection 0
couchbase_1   | curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'cb'
stormimage_couchbase_1 exited with code 6